# Installing Mapsforge-Mapwriter-plugin

Tags: openstreetmap

I'm trying to install the mapsforge-mapwriter-plugin for osmosis but I cant get it working.

I tryed the normal shellbased version and the Ways that are mentioned on the page: "http://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/wiki/GettingStartedMapWriter", but no way worked at my PC.

Neither does a directory called Application Data exists on my Hard Drive, Nor do i get the line: "2. Copy the downloaded plugin to subdirectory plugins in the current directory" which sould the current directory be in this scenario, the folder were i extractet osm or doesnt the actual folder mether.

Nor does the third way work, probably i do something wrong, i extracted the MapWriter.jar in the osmosis-folder, one time to the subfolder plugins(which i had to create manualy), one time to the osmosis/bin-folder and one in the osmosis-folder it self.

But the result is always the same: Errors.
in the second case, osmosis does not know the plugin and says always, command --mw unknown.

In the third case when I type in: C:\usertemp\Map\osmosis-0.40.1\bin>osmosis -plugin org.mapsforge.mapwriter.osmosis.MapFileWriterPluginLoader it says unable to load plugin class ...

I look forward to possible advices, because i really dont know how to get the plugin working

Answer (score 5):

I also tried various ways, but the only one that made Osmosis plugin run was after doing the following:

> Put the plugin jar into the `$OSMOSIS_HOME/lib/default` directory and add the
>   `org.openstreetmap.osmosis.plugin.elasticsearch.elasticsearchWriterPluginLoader`
>    (full namespace of your plugin loader) line into the
>   `$OSMOSIS_HOME/config/osmosis-plugins.conf` file (create it if
>   necessary).

*-- Procedure extracted from the [elasticsearch-osmosis-plugin](https://github.com/ncolomer/elasticsearch-osmosis-plugin#12-install-elasticsearch-osmosis-plugin)'s README*

You can also edit the `$OSMOSIS_HOME/config/plexus.conf` and add it a line such as `load ${app.home}/lib/plugins/*.jar` with `${app.home}/lib/plugins/` directory containing your plugin.

Comment: This worked, except this is the line that needs to go in $OSMOSIS_HOME/config/osmosis-plugins.conf:
org.mapsforge.map.writer.osmosis.MapFileWriterPluginLoader

Answer (score 3):

Just tried to follow the same procedure from http://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/wiki/GettingStartedMapWriter#Plugin_Installation, it really is screwed up a bit.

Putting `mapsforge.jar` into `$OSMOSIS_HOME/lib/default` did the trick however. Note that I did not use `-plugin` option, just copied the file and launched `osmosis --read-xml ... --mapfile-writer file ...`

Answer (score 0):

Totally agree with @Osman-pasha i haven't seen the [docs](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis/Detailed_Usage_0.47#Plugin_Tasks) about plugging installation help me once.

here is a bit more detail on how to get your dependencies installed at least on windows (for dummies such as myself):

1. first you need to find the right plugin `.jar-with-dependencies` file. most pluggin libraries offer you a link to maven and sonatype. I could never find what I was looking for in them. I finally found the plugin i needed [here](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/mapsforge/) in a sonatype repository (you might want to scroll down as there are a bunch of different versions).
2. download `.jar-with-dependencies` file you need and paste it into `$OSMOSIS_HOME/lib/default`.

and thats it. it should work with no further messing around in the plugin directory